# Select specific rows from dataframe and store them into a folder

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame of this form:

```
TEXTILE                        <NA> NA                     <NA>
R290601 WOVEN TWILL             001  6                      231
<NA> NA                        <NA> NA                     <NA>
<NA> NA                        <NA> NA                     <NA>
R481400 THREAD                A1282 12                    A0399
LINING / HEELGRIP:             <NA> NA                     <NA>
0091375 PURE SOCK               001  6                      072
R282380 SOFTLIN W/FELT          001  6                      072
R282480 MICROFIBRE              001  6                      F72
R281200 ARTIFICIAL              001  6                      072
```

What I want to do is to check the name of every row of the 1st column and if it starts with a number (ie: 0091375), or one letter and then a number (ie: R290601) then store the whole row into a folder which will have the same name and 2 sub-folders   that will have the values of the 2nd and 3rd row respectively. For example, the first row cell is called **TEXTILE**, so i want to skip it. The second row cell that starts with **R290601**, will be stored into a folder in my computer called **R290601** that will have 2 subfolders: one named **001  6** and one named **231**. Does anyone have a clue on how to do that in R?

Comment: "it starts with a number" - does it mean that "23%(@" is accepted?

Comment: I am not sure if all symbols are accepted. I think not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with regular expressions (to keep the rows you are interested in).

For example, i am assuming your `data.frame` is `df` and your column names are `x1`, `x2`, `x3` and `x4` respectively.

```
df[grepl("^[0-9]|^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*", df$x1), ]
```

Where `grepl("^[0-9]|^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*", df$x1)` is either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Explanation on grepl:

If `df$x1` starts with a number `^[0-9]` then TRUE

OR `|`

If `df$x1` starts with a letter followed by a number and anything after `^[a-zA-Z][0-9].*` then TRUE

In any other case the `grepl` will result in `FALSE`

Once you have your final `data.frame` loop through it and save each row on the paths you want.

**Save in path**

I am assuming here that you want to create the folder path, and then store the info within.

```
pth <- "C:/Users/dimitris_ps/Desktop/"

# Iteratate within each row of df
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  # Create 1st path
  dir.create(paste0(pth , df$x1[i]))
  # Create 2nd and 3rd paths
  dir.create(paste0(pth , df$x1[i], "/", paste0(df$x2[i], df$x3[i])))
  dir.create(paste0(pth , df$x1[i], "/",df$x4[i]))

  # write data.frame row as txt
  write.table(df[i, ], file=paste0(pth, df$x1[i], "/", df$x1[i],".txt"), sep=";")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it worked! So now i want to loop through the final dataframe, check the name of every cell in the 1st column and create a folder in my computer with the same name. How is it possible to do that?

Comment: Yes,this is what I meant, thanks. There's another issue though: it successfully creates the 1st folder with the corresponding subfolders, but only this one. The next row, which has a name : **009-1373 PURE LINING 0,6-0,8 MM   *with perforated L3-0,3** gives: `Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
` and this warning :`In dir.create(paste0(pth, df$x1[i])) :
  cannot create dir 'C:\Users\Dev\Desktop\Joe\009-1373 PURE LINING 0,6-0,8 MM   *with perforated L3-0,3', reason 'Invalid argument' `.

Comment: Ok. I thought they where different. Then you have to check if the path exists and if it doesn`t then creat it. With an if statement

Answer (score 1):

I assume that "it starts with a number" means just this, i.e. "23%(@" is accepted, otherwise `grep` needs slightly different regular expression.

```
ind <- grep("^([A-Za-z]|)[0-9]+", df[,1])
df.filtered <- df[ind,]
write.table(df.filtered, "myfile.dat")
```

Comment: Can you explain me what these 3 lines do? I'm very new to R and need some guidance. Thanks

Comment: Can you respond my question in comments?

Comment: What different regular expression would it need?

Comment: Depends what exactly do you mean by "it starts with a number (ie: 0091375), or one letter and then a number (ie: R290601)" .  Also, my program does not deal with folders.  It just writes all the accepted records to one file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick to get the rows you want first :

```
 test <- "TEXTILE" #Aka df[1,1]
!(is.na(as.numeric(substr(test,1,1)))&&is.na(as.numeric(substr(test,2,2))))
```

This gives us FALSE. And with the others cases :

```
 test <- "R02787" #Aka df[i,1]
 test <- "022449" #Aka df[i+1,1]
```

This will gives us TRUE, so you can already select the rows by looping through some apply and checking iff the condition is TRUE or FALSE.